# Can't set DIV equal to another DIV HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

for some reason, my wrapper div won't equal the same height as my maincontent div. I'll post the code and I would love if someone could help me understand why. Also, I can use jquery if need be

Javascript:

```
var wrap=document.getElementById('wrapper');
var left=document.getElementById('maincontent').style.height;

wrap.style.height=left;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Main Content" -->

    <div id="maincontent">

    </div>

    <!-- TemplateEndEditable --><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Background image" -->

    <div id="image" style="background-image: ;">

    </div>
```

Comment: You should clarify your question and include a jsfiddle / codepen example of the script for others to work it out quicker.

The question itself though - are you saying you want the maincontent div to fill the wrapper div to the same exact dimensions? You have a second div within the wrapper, so unless you float that one or mess with the positioning, your maincontent div is not gonna be able to spread the entire height with something in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I have guessed right, but . . .

One possible cause of what you describe is the presence of a `float` instruction in the `maincontent` DIV.

<kbd>[**See this jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pq586yu0/)</kbd>

In the example, the wrapper DIV is the wrong height -- it ignores the presence of the maincontent DIV, and the maincontent DIV appears to be below it.

This is caused by the `float:left` instruction in the maincontent DIV. A `float` will remove that DIV from the HTML flow, and the parent DIV will be missing that height. *In fact, the maincontent DIV is overflowing the wrapper DIV.*

**SOLUTION:**

Place a `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` on the parent DIV (that is, on the wrapper DIV).

<kbd>[**See this jsFiddle demo of the solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/pq586yu0/1/)</kbd>

---

Note:

`position:absolute` and `position:fixed` will also remove DIVs out of the flow. However, they cannot be "fixed" by using `overflow:________`. Manually setting the height of the containing DIV, or using javascript or some other wizardry may be necessary.

Comment: Yes this was perfect. I knew something about my HTML was making it why my wrapper did nothing. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

1- If you wan to get the rendered height of element use one of the **clientHeight** or **offsetHeight** or **scrollHeight** instead of **style.height**

2-  make sure that wrapper has closing tag `</div>`

3- when setting height of element don't forget "px" after height value.

4- If you have images without height set for them in your div, you have to wait for images to be loaded before triggering height function. you may use `$(window).load` or some other methods...

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between ele.style.height and ele.clientHeight.

I wrote a demo here,

http://jsbin.com/ninure/edit?html,css,js,console,output

May it help.