# Html elements move as the page is resized

Tags: html, css, debugging

So I made a simple fixed header, but when I render the page on a non-full sized window and then maximize the window the text seems to change its position.

It also does this if I augment the window size reasonably, in addition to that, sometimes the image gets distorted.

In the html body tag:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="user-info">
            <img class="fit-height" id="avatar" src="add_ons/sources/images/t/avatar.png"/>
            <p id="name" >BALL</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the css:

```
#header{    

    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;

}

#user-info{

    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    left: 2%;
    top: 10%;
}

#avatar{

    height: 100%;
    dispaly: block;

}

#name{

    height: 100%;
    dispaly: block;
    float: right

}
```

What happens if I maximize the window:
[image: On Chrome]

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sy764/79/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out !

```css
#header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;/*what u want..*/
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
}

#user-info {
  height: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
}
#avatar {
  margin:0.5%;
  height: 80%;
  dispaly: inline;
}

#name {
  dispaly: inline-block;
  margin-top:-30px;
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="user-info">
    <img class="fit-height" id="avatar" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    <p id="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The word `ball` jumps down when you spell `display:block` correctly. Otherwise, the css instruction is misspelled (`dispaly:block`) and ignored.

The `display:block` instruction will turn your image from an inline element (beside other elements) -- which it normally is -- into a block element, that must be on its own line.

So, if you want the image and the word to be side by side, do not use `display:block` on the image, and use `float:left` on the `<p>` tag.

However, note that `float:left` will remove an element from the HTML flow and the parent DIV will not account for its height.  See this SO answer for an example of this phenomenon:

[Can't set DIV equal to another DIV HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573227/cant-set-div-equal-to-another-div-html-javascript/34573696#34573696)