# body and container fix width in html and css

Tags: html, css

Good day! I have a problem of my simple website and I am sure that this is a simple problem that I cant fix in my own.

Here is my html code.

index.html

```
  <body>
<header> my gallery </header>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
<img src="#" alt="img"/>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

style.css

```
 body {
 margin: 20px;
 }
header {
text-align: center;
}

.container {
padding: 20px;
background: pink;
}
.box {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}
```

what I want to do is I want to fix the width of container to fit the width of the screen size of screen monitor. the body has a margin of 20px and the container has a padding of 20px. If the browser is in the full size it work will but if I will re size the browser the container re size too. I want to fix the container width so that the class box wont re align.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `display: inline-block` to `.container`?

Comment: mmh.. my problem is not the box class inside the gallery, my problem is the fix width of the container that have 20px margin to the body. maybe my question is not clear because I have poor English,. .hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem:

```
1. Use percent values for width, and
2. Group horizontal rows in DIVs, also using widths set in percents
```

As it is now, when you resize the screen, each `.box` DIV will drop to the row below.

If you create horizontal rows of DIVs and place the `.box` DIVs inside the `.row` DIVs, then when the screen re-sizes, the width of each DIV (and of the picture image within) will also get smaller. Each row will KEEP the same number of images on the row.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/emx3gbv9/1/)</kbd>

EXAMPLE:

**HTML:**

```
<header> my gallery </header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" alt="img"/></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" alt="img"/></div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" alt="img"/></div>
        <div class="box"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" alt="img"/></div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
body {margin:20px;}
header {text-align:center;}
.container {background:pink;}
.box {float:left;width:32%;height:auto;}

.row {width:100%;margin-left:20px;overflow:hidden;}
```

---

ALSO NOTE that in your example, the pink background does not extend to the bottom of your gallery.

That is because of the `.float` css instruction. Here is an explanation of what is going on there.

[Can't set DIV equal to another DIV HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573227/cant-set-div-equal-to-another-div-html-javascript/34573696#34573696)

---

***UPDATE***

jsFiddle Demo updated to add this line in the CSS:

```
.box img{width:100%;height:auto;}
```

That sets the width of the image to 100% of the `.box` it is in. The height is auto-adjusted, so the image keeps its aspect ratio.

Comment: There is anyway to make the container fix? i tried to set the width to 1000px but there are many screen size of monitor right? my IT Instructor has a wide monitor and my monitor is a smaller than him..  so I set the width to 1000px there is possible that my page change to the wide screen?

Comment: Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) to deal with different sized monitors - that is what it was designed for. If you use percents for your widths, then the images will be large on large screens and tiny on tiny screens. The images will grow/shrink with screen size. To force the images to grow/shrink (and keep aspect ratio), set the width of the image with percent, and use `height:auto`.  I should have put that in my answer (I will update it now).

Comment: Good idea - this answer is teaching you what bootstrap does for you.  Also note that [you can use @media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to dynamically adjust the CSS as the screen size changes. Media queries are incredible -- learn it!  (Bootstrap uses it heavily. Also note that with Bootstrap there is also a lot of manual coding to do, to tweak BS to work for your website)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix container,you must set a fixed width,like this:

html:

```
<body>
<header> my gallery </header>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="#" alt="img"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
 body {
    margin: 20px;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    padding: 20px;
    background: pink;
    width:1020px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't know If this is you want to express meaning?

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if the screen size of monitor is 1366 wide? so the margin of the container from the body is change? the margin from the container to the body is 20px and the margin of the body to the html is 20px. is that width: 1000px is a default of width of the screen monitor?

Comment: It has a litter messy about your description; I think your meaning as above about I edit;

Comment: You can run  it to try;(I add border in container just to for try,you can delete;)@MGBC